# wkhtmltopdf patched qt?

Tags: qt, ubuntu-12.04, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to convert multiple URLs to PDF. However, when I compile wkhtmltopdf or run `apt-get install wkhtmltopdf` and try, it says:

> Error: This version of wkhtmltopdf is build against an unpatched version of QT, and does not support more then one input document.

If I use the static version, I get Segmentation fault error.

How do I build wkhtmltopdf against a patched version of QT, or are there any other solutions besides converting one by one and reuniting?

My OS is Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit. Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First check out the source

```
 git clone git://gitorious.org/~antialize/qt/antializes-qt.git wkhtmltopdf-qt
 cd wkhtmltopdf-qt
 git checkout 4.8.4
 QTDIR=. ./bin/syncqt
```

Qt must be configured, a good set of configuration options for qt can found by looking at the output of

```
cat ../wkhtmltopdf/static_qt_conf_base ../wkhtmltopdf/static_qt_conf_linux | sed -re 's/#.*//'
cd wkhtmltopdf-qt
./configure -nomake tools,examples,demos,docs,translations -opensource -prefix "../wkqt"
```

And Qt compiled and installed (this will take a while)

```
make -j3 && make install
cd ..
```

You must now run qmake in the wkhtmltopdf folder.

```
cd wkhtmltopdf
../wkqt/bin/qmake
```

[Archived Google Code link](https://web.archive.org/web/20130727035829/http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/wiki/compilation).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I think new versions will work using precompiled binaries but not sure.

Answer (score 4):

Go http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html and download appropriate build.
Its already patched with QT.

```
wkhtmltopdf --help
    or
wkhtmltopdf -V
```

should show

```
Description:
  Converts one or more HTML pages into a PDF document, using wkhtmltopdf patched qt.
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the "Bleeding Edge" downloads are not built with patched qt. (ex. wkhtmltox-0.13.0-alpha-7b36694_msvc2013-win64)

Answer (score 2):

Download the appropriate debian (*.deb) package from [wkhtmltopdf.org](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html).

*New to Ubuntu ? To install, double click the downloaded *.deb file.*