# How to install wkhtmltopdf with patched qt?

Tags: qt, wkhtmltopdf

I want to convert html to pdf, and I use wkhtmltopdf.

But print size is smaller than I supposed.
I want to try `--disable-smart-shrinking` option but error occured like

```
$ xvfb-run -- /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf --disable-smart-shrinking $INPUT $OUTPUT
The switch --disable-smart-shrinking, is not support using unpatched qt, and will be ignored.Loading page (1/2)
Printing pages (2/2)
Done
```

Maybe I have to install wkhtmltopdf with patched qt, but I don't know how to install.

I saw following size, but gitorious.org doesn't work.

[wkhtmltopdf patched qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981960/wkhtmltopdf-patched-qt)

My OS is Ubuntu14.04, and wkhtmltopdf version is 0.12.2.1

If you know other reason to be printed smaller, tell me please. thanks.

Comment: `--disable-smart-shrinking` option problem is resolve by install from http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html. But size problem is still occured.

Comment: I think you need a new question for the size problem. the size problem depends on HTML or wkhtmltopdf or other. so add more information to the new question.

Comment: ok, I will make new question for the size problem. Install problem is resolbed, thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can install `wkhtmltopdf` with `--disable-smart-shrinking` option from
[wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html).

Download and Install it.

http://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt

The Document say

> wkhtmltopdf 0.12.2.1 (with patched qt)

and

> --disable-smart-shrinking       Disable the intelligent shrinking strategy
>                                         used by WebKit that makes the pixel/dpi
>                                         ratio none constant

Answer (score 84):

This straightforward solution (no need to install xvfb, neither compiling QT neither wkhtmltopdf) works like a charm on my Debian Jessie server :

```
cd mytmpfolder
wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.4/wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz
sudo tar xvf wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz
sudo mv wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmlto* /usr/bin/
#create simple html test file
echo "<html><body>test</body></html>" >> test.html
#perform conversion
sudo wkhtmltopdf  --disable-smart-shrinking  --lowquality --enable-external-links --enable-internal-links test.html test.pdf
```

Comment: Verified solution for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: also with 0.12.4 on debian

Comment: Worked for me on UBUNTU 16

Comment: Updated Solution https://gist.github.com/Rajeshr34/2e9b2438ff142e51c729b4b9b772680a

Comment: Works like a charm on Debian Jessie with wkhtmltopdf version 0.12.4. Thank you!

Comment: last command `sudo wkhtmltopdf  --disable-smart-shrinking  --lowquality --enable-external-links --enable-internal-links test.html test.pdf` gave error `wkhtmltopdf: error while loading shared libraries: libXrender.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: I installed libxrender1 with `sudo apt-get install libxrender1` now it give me error `Error: Failed loading page http://test.html (sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with --load-error-handling ignore)
Exit with code 1 due to network error: HostNotFoundError`

Comment: @Saifee page you mention  http://test.html   no longer exists however now even https pages work fine

Comment: @Saifee Indeed you need a file to test its pdf conversion. I updated my answer.

Comment: Still usefull (on CentOs 7) ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 39):

#### Steps to Install Version 0.12.3 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Because I wasted way too much time tracking this down, here it is for others stumbling on this:

```
cd ~
wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.3/wkhtmltox-0.12.3_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz
tar vxf wkhtmltox-0.12.3_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz 
cp wkhtmltox/bin/wk* /usr/local/bin/
```

And you can confirm with:

```
$ wkhtmltopdf --version
wkhtmltopdf 0.12.3 (with patched qt)
```

Btw, I chose 0.12.3 instead of 0.12.4 because of a strange page sizing issue, discussed [here](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/3226).

Comment: Worked for me in a dockerfile on ubuntu 16.04. Thanks

Comment: Worked for me Debian 9.0

Answer (score 8):

The solution that @raj added in the comments worked for me in Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS so I decided to include an updated answer here:

```
sudo apt-get install xfonts-75dpi
wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/releases/download/0.12.6.1-2/wkhtmltox_0.12.6.1-2.jammy_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltox_0.12.6.1-2.jammy_amd64.deb
sudo apt --fix-broken install
rm wkhtmltox_0.12.6.1-2.jammy_amd64.deb
```

Then confirm that it installed the patched qt version:

```
wkhtmltopdf -V
=> wkhtmltopdf 0.12.6.1 (with patched qt)
```

Original gist from Raj.

https://gist.github.com/Rajeshr34/2e9b2438ff142e51c729b4b9b772680a

Answer (score 5):

Here are the simple steps to install the wkhtmltopdf 0.12.5 (with patched qt) using a shell script for Ubuntu 14.04, 15.04, 16.04, 18.04, and 20.04.

Step 1. create a shell file

```
cd /tmp && nano install_wkhtmltopdf.sh
```

Step 2. paste the below code

```
WKHTMLTOX_X64=https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.5/wkhtmltox_0.12.5-1.trusty_amd64.deb
WKHTMLTOX_X32=https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.5/wkhtmltox_0.12.5-1.trusty_i386.deb

sudo apt-get install wget git python-pip gdebi -y

if [ "`getconf LONG_BIT`" == "64" ];then
  _url=$WKHTMLTOX_X64
else
  _url=$WKHTMLTOX_X32
fi
sudo wget $_url
sudo gdebi --n `basename $_url`
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/bin
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage /usr/bin
```

Step 3. make the file executable

```
sudo chmod +x install_wkhtmltopdf.sh
```

Step 4. execute the shell script

```
./install_wkhtmltopdf.sh
```

Comment: if you get "E: Package 'libpng12-0' has no installation candidate" be sure you install the proper package compatible to your distro. See here https://askubuntu.com/a/1371063/276370

Answer (score 0):

Updated solution posted by @cortex, not completly works for Debian 12.2. I reached problem with missing libjpeg-turbo8 without candidate to install via `sudo apt-get install libjpeg-turbo8`

To install that You need to do

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/libj/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo8_2.1.2-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./libjpeg-turbo8_2.1.2-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install xfonts-75dpi
wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/releases/download/0.12.6.1-2/wkhtmltox_0.12.6.1-2.jammy_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltox_0.12.6.1-2.jammy_amd64.deb
sudo apt --fix-broken install
rm wkhtmltox_0.12.6.1-2.jammy_amd64.deb
```

And after that i recieve wkhtmltopdf with patched qt (i need that to create pdf with flags `--header-html` and `--footer-html`. Default version from `apt-get` dosen't have this feature.