# odoo- warning Wkhtmltopdf failed (error code: -6). Message: The switch --header-spacing, is not support using unpatched qt

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I installed odoo 9 under ubuntu server 15.10 with wkhtmltopdf 0.12.2.4.

Everytime I print sales order, it raises error:

> **Odoo Warning - Warning**
>
> Wkhtmltopdf failed (error code: -6). Message: The switch --header-spacing, is not support using unpatched qt, and
> will be ignored.The switch --header-html, is not support using
> unpatched qt, and will be ignored.The switch --footer-html, is not
> support using unpatched qt, and will be ignored.QXcbConnection: Could
> not connect to display.

I've tried to solved this bug but still failed, help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't take credit for this answer, but I was able to solve the issue using the solution provided by Tsounabe here:  [Stack Overflow Patched QT Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34479040/how-to-install-wkhtmltopdf-with-patched-qt)

The only thing I can add is that I changed the version (0.12.3) in each line to the latest (0.12.4) and was able to use the latest version to accomplish the same thing.

Good luck!