# Python/wkhtmltopdf PDF generation in Ubuntu generates a file size 20 times larger than the same file on Windows

Tags: python-3.x, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit, windows-11, ubuntu-22.04

I'm using Python 3.10's '[pdfkit](https://pypi.org/project/pdfkit/)' (1.0.0), which calls '[wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/)' (0.12.6) in the background, to generate a PDF using code-generated HTML as the source.

The HTML has a base64 encoded ttf font embedded and there are six small (<1k) base64 encoded images per page along with text and divs. The PDF document is only 8 A4 pages.

The call to create the PDF is simply:

```
pdfkit.from_string(source_html, "filename.pdf")
```

Using Windows 11 the file created is ~450 KB

Using Ubuntu 22 the file created is ~9 MB

The files, when opened, are visibly identical so what is causing this file size discrepancy and how can I fix it?

Comment: Hi @Dave I have a similar problem, did you manage to discover the origin of the problem?

Comment: I found out the difference, although didn't find a solution to it. It would appear that on Linux the PDF is generated such that the content is just one big image.

On windows, it's text and images as you'd expect.

You can test this by trying to select the text in the different PDFs.

I believe it's an issue in the wkhtmltopdf binary for Linux.

Comment: @Dave I have a PDF with 300 images and numbers, 3.3MB on Windows, 9MB on Ubuntu (still 300 images). I tested this by "copy"ing an image into GIMP. Also InkScape shows the layout is just as I intended. I suspect the cause is non-free algorithms being declined by Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this today. The image heavy PDF was 3 times bigger on Ubuntu than on Windows.

Firstly, I added the wkhtmltopdf option, "image-quality" to my `from_string`/`from_file` options `dict`.

```
pdfkit.from_file("templatised.html", "out.pdf", options=options)
```

I regression test this on Windows and it makes no noticeable difference. I set the quality the same as I have used for the constituent images. I dislike the thought of applying lossy encoding twice, but I chose `wkhtmltopdf` and I will stick with it.

Now, on Linux the option is required, but [the python-pdfkit repo](https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit?tab=readme-ov-file#installation) warns:

> debian/ubuntu repos have reduced functionality (because it compiled without the wkhtmltopdf QT patches)

This doesn't identify `image-quality` as missing functionality. Quality defaults to 94, which might explain the huge file sizes.

Setting `image-quality` produces a warning when taking the OS-supplied `wkhtmltopdf` installation:

> The switch --image-quality, is not support using unpatched qt, and will be ignored

The [python-pdfkit link](https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit?tab=readme-ov-file#installation) before, links to solutions to this, which are out of date. I could not find a solution for Debian bookworm, so had to revert to bullseye.

Precompiled `wkhtmltopdf` binaries for each OS can be found [here](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html#stable). [`wkhtmltopdf`](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf) was archived January 2023. [wkhtmltopdf/packaging](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging) was archived August 2023. I don't expect any updates.

Here is the script from [JazzCore](https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit/blob/master/ci/before-script.sh) to install the QT patched version:

```
WKHTML2PDF_VERSION='0.12.6-1'

sudo apt install -y build-essential xorg libssl-dev libxrender-dev wget
wget "https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/releases/download/${WKHTML2PDF_VERSION}/wkhtmltox_${WKHTML2PDF_VERSION}.bionic_amd64.deb"
sudo apt install -y ./wkhtmltox_${WKHTML2PDF_VERSION}.bionic_amd64.deb
```

They are targetting bionic_amd64 and 0.12.6-1. I want Debian bullseye and 0.12.6-2, which I had to make the appropriate changes to use.

https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/releases/download/0.12.6.1-2/wkhtmltox_0.12.6.1-2.bullseye_amd64.deb

Several other SO posts validated my approach, such as:

[How to install wkhtmltopdf with patched qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34479040/how-to-install-wkhtmltopdf-with-patched-qt)

See also https://pythonspeed.com/articles/base-image-python-docker-images/ for advice on migrating from bullseye-slim docker images to the more recent Ubuntu Jammy.