# Remove some local links when exporting markdown to HTML

Tags: html, markdown, href, wkhtmltopdf, grip

I occasionally export `README.md`s to pdfs using `grip` then `wkhtmltopdf`. Recently I noticed that the generated pdf had links in markdown headings pointing to file locations in my own computer. I want either `grip` to stop generating the `href` within the exported markdown headings, or `wkhtmltopdf` to stop trying to be smart and setting the links relative to paths in my computer. How can I do this?

I checked manual pages for `wkhtmltopdf` and the help of `grip`, but didn't find a clear option to disable this.

For completeness: The page source shows for example:

```
<h1 id="user-content-heading-1"><a class="heading-link" href="#heading-1">Heading 1<span aria-hidden="true" class="octicon octicon-link"></span></a></h1>
<p>Sample text1</p>
<h2 id="user-content-heading-2"><a class="heading-link" href="#heading-2">Heading 2<span aria-hidden="true" class="octicon octicon-link"></span></a></h2>
<p>Sample text2</p>
```

These hrefs are then converted by `wkhtmltopdf` to a local file link, something like `file://path/to/html`.

Comment: can you share an example of such md file having the links you are talking about? do those links exist in the md source file? and if yes, what's the resource they are linking to? is it an absolute url? and why/how it gets transformed in a local path?

Comment: Added the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I couldn't find an easy way to get a patched QT for `wkhtmltopdf`, I used `awk` to find local hrefs and delete them: `awk '{sub(/ href="(#[^"]+)"/,""); print $0}'`

Pass the output of `grip` through this and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt), you can disable local links :

`wkhtmltopdf --disable-internal-links` : Do not make local links.

Comment: I tried with this switch and got: `The switch --disable-internal-links, is not support using unpatched qt, and will be ignored`
I'm on Fedora Linux, how am I supposed to get a "patched qt"?

Comment: @td211 [How to install wkhtmltopdf with patched qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34479040/how-to-install-wkhtmltopdf-with-patched-qt)